# Rss Reader app not returning title?

Tags: android, asynchronous, rss

I have followed a tutorial which shows me how to create an Rss feed reading app, but upon running it...it only shows, in the listView, the below LogCat:

```
08-25 12:33:11.507: E/RESULT(13889): [com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@4306f848, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@4306fcb0, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@4306ff90, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@430702d8, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43070478, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@430705d0, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43070788, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43070ae8, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43070ca0, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43070e50, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43071028, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43071208, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43071398, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@430715b0, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43071768, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43071918, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43071ae8, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43071cd8, com.example.rssapplication.RssItem1@43071e88]
```

This is the main class code:

```
*package com.example.rssapplication;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class DirectRSS extends Activity{



     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.directrss);


            GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

            // Start download RSS task
            task.execute("http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml");



            //Set to portrait, so that every time the view changes; it does not run the DB query again...
            setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


        }



     private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem1> > {
            @Override
            protected List<RssItem1> doInBackground(String... urls) {

                // Debug the task thread name
                Log.d("ITCRssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

                try {
                    // Create RSS reader
                    RssReader1 rssReader = new RssReader1(urls[0]);

                    // Parse RSS, get items
                    return rssReader.getItems();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ITCRssReader", e.getMessage());
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem1> result) {

                // Get a ListView from main view
                ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                //result = RssItem1.this.getTitle();             
                // Create a list adapter
                ArrayAdapter<RssItem1> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem1>(DirectRSS.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);*


  // Set list adapter for the ListView
            itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.e("RESULT", result.toString());

            // Set list view item click listener
            itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener1(result, DirectRSS.this));
        }
    }  






 }
```

RssItem1:

```
package com.example.rssapplication;

public class RssItem1 {

    private String title;
    private String link;


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }



}
```

It does not give any error messages, I think it may have something to do with 'result' not actually containing the title.

Any help will be appreciated.

I can incude the other class files I am using, if anyone wishes to see them

Comment: In your project in class RssItem please override toString method and run it once again. Now it's giving you address in memory of object.

Comment: Hi, I do not know what you mean exactly....please could you show me? I have included my RssItem class in the above code now.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening now is `ArrayAdapter` takes each `RssItem1` from the array calls its `toString()` method and populates the `ListView`. Since you have not overridden this method it calls `toString()` of the `Object` class. You can try and override this method in `RssItem1` class to see how it works.

As a solution you might want to implement the `BaseAdapter` interface in order to populate views in the list correctly. [example](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/#sthash.YIh5BOZp.dpbs)

Edit:
This is just an example, tweak it depending on what you have in the class.

```
public class RssItem1 {
/* your code */

    @Override
    public String toString () {
         return this.title + ":" + this.description;
    }
}
```

As for the `BaseAdapter` you can just follow a tutorial on the link.

Comment: Hey, I am not exactly sure what you mean sorry (I am new to android development)....could you possibly show me in the code? Thanks!

Comment: see my edit.
you might also want to checkout what `toString()` does [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Comment: If you want to print any type of object in Java in human readable format you should override toString() that method is classed always if you want to print object as String.